# Show records where a value exist in all instances of a field by group

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to figure out a way to show all records in table where a specific field does not contain certain values - table layout is:

```
id
tenant_id
request_action
request_id
request_status
hash
```

Each request_id could have multiple actions so it could look like:

```
1    1    email    1234    1    ffffd9b00cf893297ab737243c2b921c
2    1    email    1234    0    ffffd9b00cf893297ab737243c2b921c
3    1    email    1234    0    ffffd9b00cf893297ab737243c2b921c

4    1    email    1235    1    a50ee458c9878190c24cdf218c4ac904
5    1    email    1235    1    a50ee458c9878190c24cdf218c4ac904
6    1    email    1235    1    a50ee458c9878190c24cdf218c4ac904

7    1    email    1236    1    58c2869bc4cc38acc03038c7bef14023
8    1    email    1236    2    58c2869bc4cc38acc03038c7bef14023
9    1    email    1236    2    58c2869bc4cc38acc03038c7bef14023
```

Request_id can either be 0 (pending), 1 (sent) or 2 (failed) - I want to find all hashes where all the request_status within that hash are set to 1.

In the above two examples `a50ee458c9878190c24cdf218c4ac904` should return as a match as all the request_status are 1 but `ffffd9b00cf893297ab737243c2b921c` should not as, whilst it contains a 1, it also contains some 0's and `58c2869bc4cc38acc03038c7bef14023` should not as, again whilst it contains a 1, it also contains some 2's

I tried:

```
SELECT 
   * 
from 
  table 
where request_action='email' and request_status!=0 and request_status!=2 
group by hash
```

However, this doesn't give me the result I need - how can I return the hashes only where request_status is set to 1 for all the instances of that hash?

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`.  Your query doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would need a `group by` here. You'd want to do a `group by` if you were going to concat data using `GROUP_CONCAT`, or other aggregate functions (`sum`, `max`, etc)

Also, instead of doing multiple negative conditions in your where clause (`request_status !=0 and request_status !=2`), why not just get the status you want?

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE request_action = 'email' AND request_status = 1
```

**Update Based on Your Comment**

If you don't want to return any hashes that have the status of 0, or 2. You can do this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    test t
WHERE 
    request_action = 'email' AND request_status = 1 
    AND HASH NOT IN (SELECT HASH FROM test WHERE request_status IN (0, 2))
```

Just make sure you have an index on hash, otherwise this is going to be really slow.

Comment: That query would return all 3 hashes above as each of them has a request_status of 1 included?

Comment: According to your data, it would return 5 hashes. 3 of which would be the same `a50ee458c9878190c24cdf218c4ac904` because they all have the same status of 1

Comment: Yes but I don't want it to return 58c2869bc4cc38acc03038c7bef14023 or ffffd9b00cf893297ab737243c2b921c as those hash do not ONLY contain request_status of 1

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table temp select hash from your_table where 
request_status=1 group by hash

Alter table temp add index(hash)

Delete from temp where hash IN (select hash from temp 
where request_status!=1 group by hash)

Select * from your_table where hash IN(select hash from 
temp)
```